# Multiple proxies in app.config file

Tags: .net, proxy, app-config

we have a client who wants us to put in multiple proxies to be used by our app. We were using one, and had the following setup in the `app.config` file, as so...

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://their.proxy.address:1234"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

This was working fine. Now, the client has decided they want us to use two proxy servers. I've tried googling, but cannot find how to do this.

I've tried (multiple proxy nodes)...

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://their-a.proxy.address:1234"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
      <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://their-b.proxy.address:1234"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

This complains about only one `proxy` node being allowed below `defaultProxy`. 
I've also tried (multiple defaultProxy nodes)...

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://their-a.proxy.address:1234"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"
        proxyaddress="http://their-b.proxy.address:1234"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

But then the program throws initialization errors for the various classes in the code.

Can anyone point me to how to add multiple proxies? 
Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @dawncode - nope. The client wound up going back to only one proxy, so it became a non-issue for us.

Comment: I am interested in this question. Does anyone know how to do this?